# algorithm from cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, opencv3.0, grayscale

I want to make a program to convert RGB images to grayscale in large quantities and I use this code

```
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))] 
for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,gray)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
```

can you guys explain to me 
how does the work or algorithm of cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

or more precisely how the program code snippet can convert RGB images to grayscale? how is the calculation?

does the algoritm use the formula `R + G + B / 3`  for all pixels in an image so its can convert to grayscale images??

Comment: It's in [the opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor). The formula is more complex than just a mean across the 3 channels.

Comment: in the document, the dot symbol is "." in "RGB [A] to Gray: Y ← 0.299⋅R + 0.587⋅G + 0.114⋅B" does that mean multiplied?

And what does the "Y" mean? are this grayscale symbol?

Comment: Yes for both of your questions: Grey = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is slightly more complicated, but you are broadly correct. The human eye is most sensitive to green light, then red, then blue. The greyscale value is calculated as the weighted average of the three channel values.